# Using a list variable for ECS task in container_definitions with terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In terraform I am attempting to pass a variable (list) to a module that we built. This variable needs to be used within a `aws_ecs_task_definition` resource in the `container_definitions`.
Right now I am just starting with an empty default list defined as a variable:

```
variable "task_enviornment" {
  type        = "list"
  default = []
}
```

My ECS task definition looks like this:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "ecs_task_definition" {
  family                   = "${var.ecs_family}"
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  task_role_arn            = "${aws_iam_role.iam_role.arn}"
  execution_role_arn       = "${data.aws_iam_role.iam_ecs_task_execution_role.arn}"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  cpu                      = "${var.fargate_cpu}"
  memory                   = "${var.fargate_memory}"

  container_definitions =<<DEFINITION
  [
    {
      "cpu": ${var.fargate_cpu},
      "image": "${var.app_image}",
      "memory": ${var.fargate_memory},
      "name": "OURNAME",
      "networkMode": "awsvpc",
      "environment": "${jsonencode(var.task_enviornment)}",
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group" : "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.fargate-logs.name}",
          "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "demo"
        }
      },
      "portMappings": [
        {
        "containerPort": ${var.app_port},
        "hostPort": ${var.app_port}
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
  DEFINITION
}
```

The part I am having a problem with with the "environment" part:

```
"environment": "${jsonencode(var.task_enviornment)}",
```

I have tried a few different ways to get this to work.

If I do `"environment": "${jsonencode(var.task_enviornment)}",`
I get `ECS Task Definition container_definitions is invalid: Error decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field ContainerDefinition.Environment of type []*ecs.KeyValuePair`

If I do `"environment": "${var.task_enviornment}",` or `"environment": ["${var.task_enviornment}"],`
I get `At column 1, line 1: output of an HIL expression must be a string, or a single list (argument 8 is TypeList) in:`
Then it just outputs the contents of `container_definitions`

I did also try adding default values and I was getting similar error messages. However I do need to be able to handle no values being sent in, so an empty list.

```
variable "task_enviornment" {
  type        = "list"
  default = [
    {
      "name" = "BUCKET",
      "value" = "test"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Theres also a typo in environment.

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of investigation and a fresh set of eyes looking at this figured out the solution. I am unsure why this fixes it, and I feel like this is likely a bug.
Needed to do 2 things to fix this.

1. Remove `type        = "list"` from the variable definition.

   `variable "task_environment" {
     default = []
   }`
2. Remove the quotes when using the variable:
   `"environment": ${jsonencode(var.task_environment)},`

Comment: Might have something to do with the lack of a comma after `type = "list"`?

Answer (score 1):

The below solution should work

in variable.tf

```
variable "app_environments_vars" {
type        = list(map(string))
default     = []
description = "environment variable needed by the application"
default = [
{
  "name" = "BUCKET",
  "value" = "test"
},{
  "name" = "BUCKET1",
  "value" = "test1"
}]
```

and in your task definition, you can use `${jsonencode(var.app_environments_vars)}` similar to

```
container_definitions =<<DEFINITION
  [
    {
      "cpu": ${var.fargate_cpu},
      "image": "${var.app_image}",
      "memory": ${var.fargate_memory},
      "name": "OURNAME",
      "networkMode": "awsvpc",
      "environment": ${jsonencode(var.app_environments_vars)},
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group" : "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.fargate-logs.name}",
          "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "demo"
        }
      },
      "portMappings": [
        {
        "containerPort": ${var.app_port},
        "hostPort": ${var.app_port}
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are trying to use the type "map" instead of lists, as showed above, the removal from type specification will work.
Example:

- List_sample = [1,2,3]
- Map_sample = { key_name = "value" }

Reference: [Terraform - Type Constraints](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/type-constraints.html)